# How to convert list of int in json to list/array of enums using Moshi?

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin, enums, moshi

I'm getting a list of ints (which are really enums) from the API. When I try to parse it, I get: `Unable to create converter for java.util.List<MyEnum>`

My adapter is currently looking like this:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class MyEnumListAnnotation

class MyEnumListAdapter {
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(@MyEnumListAnnotation myEnumList: List<MyEnum>): List<Int> {
        return myEnumList.map { it.type }
    }

    @FromJson
    @MyEnumListAnnotation
    fun fromJson(typeList: List<Int>): List<MyEnum> {
        return typeList.map { MyEnum.from(it) }
    }
}
```

I'm adding this to the network client like this:

```
Moshi.Builder()
                    .add([A lot of other adapters])
                    .add(MyEnumListAdapter())
```

And I'm using the annotation like this (in the object I want to parse to):

```
data class InfoObject(
        val id: String,
        val name: String,
        val email: String,
        val phone: String,

        @MyEnumListAnnotation
        val myEnums: List<MyEnum>
)
```

How can I write my adapter so that this is working? Thanks for all help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Moshi's `codegen` (which you should), you only need to write adapter for your `MyEnum` itself.

```
class MyEnumAdapter {
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(enum: MyEnum): Int {
        return enum.type
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(type: Int): MyEnum {
        return MyEnum.from(it)
    }
}
```

Attach the adapter to your Moshi builder the way you did it in your question. Then, update your `InfoObject`:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class InfoObject(
        @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
        @Json(name = "name") val name: String,
        @Json(name = "email") val email: String,
        @Json(name = "phone") val phone: String,
        @Json(name = "myEnums") val myEnums: List<MyEnum>
)
```

`@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` will ensure that the library will auto-create an adapter for your `InfoObject`, including an adapter for `List<MyEnum>` (the one you tried to create yourself), so you don't have to create those adapters yourself. `@Json(name="...")` is just a convention, you can omit it.

To integrate `codegen`, just add to dependencies:

```
kapt("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.3")
```

See https://github.com/square/moshi for more details.

Comment: Hmm.. I still get the same error: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<...MyEnum>

Comment: Do I somehow need to add the generated adapter to my moshi or will this happen out of the box?

Comment: Should happen out of the box. Try - after build - searching your project for `InfoObjectAdapter` class, it should be one of the auto-generated files if you have all dependencies correctly set up.
If you feel stuck, then, if possible, upload your code somewhere to github, I can then check it.

Comment: Also check this specific section, should be your use case:
https://github.com/square/moshi#built-in-type-adapters

Comment: I cannot upload the code to github since its a customers full code... The built in type adapters did not give me much. Everything works fine if I change the type from List<MyEnum> to List<Int>. When I have it as list of enums, I get error:

Comment: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<xxxxxxxx.dataclasses.InfoObject> for method APIService.xxxxx

Comment: Do you use Retrofit for your APIService?

Comment: Yes. I added this issue https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3452

Comment: Then you might have something wrongly set up in your retrofit instance.

https://github.com/phamtdat/MoshiDemo

I made a working demo that reflects your case, check out and have a look.

Comment: Nice!! Gonna take a look at the differences and see if I can figure it out. Thanks! :)

Comment: Finally got this to work! It seemed like the @ annotation was hindering the correct conversion for some reason...

Comment: I also had a gson converter factory in addition to moshi. Behavior changed based on which one I had added to retrofit first... I removed gson, and now things seems to work.